# How do I use background image on button? Mine now showing properly using css

Tags: css, nativescript

### My Problem

I am trying to replicate the following screen in NativeScript ( here is our Figma prototype ):

[image: Desired Output]

I am having problems getting the background image of the bottom navigation buttons to appear correctly.

Here is how my NativeScript view is coming out ( disregard everything except bottom nav, please )...

[image: My NativeScript Output]

Here is the latest CSS I have tried, with no luck:

```
/* Activity_icon */
.activity-button {

    background-image: url("~/images/Activity_icon.png");
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top;
    background-size: 200%;    
}
```

### Live PlayGround Code

[My code in NativeScript Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=vDEqRS&v=27)

Can anyone show me how to get my button looking as close to the prototype as possible? I have tried everything I can think of, with no luck. Thanks for looking.

Comment: I would suggest using the TabView component, provided by `tns-core-modules` with a bottom position for Android. Check out the example here -  https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-js/tree/master/app/ns-ui-widgets-category/tab-view/tabs-position-android. The example shows how to set the position of the tabs and how to set the needed icons.

Comment: The images are evidently showing (from looking at the Activity tab). You can't see them clearly because the text is oversized. Decrease text size

Comment: As suggested by @NikolayTsonev you may use the TabView component here. If you want to go with custom buttons, reduce the font size. Also looking at your image it can not be a background image, use an Image and Label component wrapped in a GridLayout.

Comment: Can anyone PLEASE show me a pure Javascript example of that TabView that you guys suggested? I see the TypeScript version, but cannot add Typescript to the current project. It is written in core JS. That example on TabView page is exactly what I need. They don't show core example though, just my luck.

Answer (score 0):

I want to share a solution I figured out:

Using @NikolayTsonev and @Manoj suggestion, I used the [Tab View Component](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-ui-widgets/tab-view#basics). Once I got it looking the way I needed in the Playground, I had to figure out a way to convert the example Playground code from Typescript to pure Javascript.

By pure chance I found out you can use: TNS CREATE , and answer the prompts. It allows me to choose TABVIEW as a template, and CORE Javascript as the language! Awesome! Nowhere is that documented, but it's there and it works! Thanks everyone for your help.